# How to diagnose malformed JObject in ASP.NET WebAPI?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api

I wrote the following method to try to diagnose a problem I'm experiencing in my application:

```
    [Route("/api/flow/test"), HttpPost]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(string), (int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Test(string id, [FromBody] JToken input)
    {            
        var result = input == null ? "Not OK" : "OK";
        return Ok(result);
    }
```

I post a large (6.5MB+) JSON body to it, and in one instance it works fine.  When I post a similar JSON with some added properties, it does not - the `input` parameter comes in as `null`.  However, both JSON validate successfully with every tool I've found that can handle their size.  Please provide some additional ideas about how to further investigate what is causing the body parameter input to be treated as null.

Answer (score 3):

One option would be to declare it as `string` instead of `JToken` and try to explicitly parse it in the action body.

This will show you two things:

1. If `input` is still empty, it's not a problem with JSON parsing
2. If parsing it explicitly fails, the JSON is indeed invalid.

Only when `input` is not null and parsing it in the body works - only then you need to deep dive into what actually happens, when you declare an action parameter as JToken.

Comment: It is a good idea, but I'm not sure how to implement it.  I'm using Postman to send the request, and if I send it as text or text/plain instead of application/json, I get a 415 unsupported media type error.  Is there some way in which I need to modify the body so that the API can accept it as a string?

Comment: Just changing it to `public async Task<IActionResult> Test(string id, [FromBody] string input)` isn't enough?

Comment: Seems like whatever is sent with that method signature is received as a null.  A co-worker has read the HttpContext.Request.Body successfully and written it to a file.  I'll update as we know more.